# how to change OpenLDAP configuration ( slapd.conf ) programmatically

Tags: api, shell, configuration, ldap, openldap

I need to make some configuration changes to slapd.conf. Changes are related to enabling SSL, enabling synch-replication etc.

For example, i need to add following block of configuration in slapd.conf to enable synch-replication over SSL :

```
TLSCACertificateFile /etc/openldap/cacerts/cacert.pem  
TLSCertificateFile /etc/openldap/certs/servercrt.pem  
TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/openldap/certs/serverkey.pem  
TLSVerifyClient never
```

Right now, I am trying to do this with shell script. Script will edit text in slapd.conf using sed, awk commands and some logic to place the text correctly in slapd.conf.
I don't think this is the best way to make configuration changes in slapd.conf.

Is there an API/commands for shell to do the same.

Please also suggest any java api for the same ?

I am using OpenLDAP.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used online configuration with the -F slapd.d option you could do it via an LDAP API.